# Como organizar meu projeto e ser mais produtivo?

Tags: php, mysql

Boa noite pessoal, sou um iniciante digamos assim, e estou com dificuldades para organizar meu projeto, pois mesmo sabendo o que quero não sei a ordem dos passos para concluir meu objetivo, e me vejo perdido diversas vezes

Tentei algumas dicas que vi em outras postagens mas nada me ajudou, tentei até mesmo o github.

Alguem poderia compartilhar as experiencias e o como se organiza para criar os projetos

Atualmente estou montando um sistema web de um e-commerce (PHP/MySQL

Sei que já haviam postagens do tipo no forum porém nenhuma das dicas me ajudou muito

Obrigado!

Comment: [Análise e Modelagem com UML](http://luizantoniopereira.com.br/downloads/publicacoes/AnaliseEModelagemComUML.pdf) disponibilizado online pelo próprio autor.

Comment: [Guia do Scrum](https://www.scrumguides.org/docs/scrumguide/v1/Scrum-Guide-Portuguese-BR.pdf) disponibilizado online pelos autores originalmente em língua inglesa e traduzido pela equipe Scrumguides.

Comment: Agradeço pela ajuda também augusto!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, José, bem vindo ao StackOverflow.

Bem... não sou avançado em PHP, mas o que eu faço com meus projetos atualmente quanto à estrutura de arquivos separo em:

```
|-root
---|class
------>Busca.class.php
---|php
------>busca.php
---|plugins
-------|bootstrap
-------|jQuery
---|view
-------index.php
---|js
-------index.js
```

Explicando basicamente: em `class` estão todas as classes que EU fiz em PHP para fazer principalmente funções de acesso ao BD, como entrada e busca de dados. Já em `php` ficam os arquivos de "controle" do php, que é para onde um form vai quando o usuário clica no botão de `submit`.

Você pode fazer isso de um jeito simples:

--index.php

```
<html>
<form action="busca.php" method="POST">
   <input type="hidden" name="form" value="teste"/>
   <input type="text" name="fieldName"/>
   <button type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
</form>
</html>
```

--busca.php

```
<?php

include_once '../class/Busca.class.php';

$filter = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'form');
if (!is_null($filter)) {
    $form = $filter;
}

switch ($form) {
   case 'teste':
      echo Busca::getTeste();
      break;
}

?>
```

--Busca.class.php

```
<?php

class Busca {
    public static function getTeste():string {
         return "teste";
    }
}
```

Bom, essa seria uma comunicação básica modularizada entre o html e o php. A medica que você vai adicionando js para envio de formulários sem a necessidade de refresh em toda a página, por exemplo, as coisas vão ficando mais interessantes.

Essa é a forma como EU organizo basicamente os meus projetos:

- view (php com html e formulários)
- php (arquivos de controle entre view e classes php)
- class (classes do php para fazer acesso ao BD e coisas mais elaboradas)

Espero ter ajudado, qualquer dúvida estou a disposição!

Comment: Amigo, agradeço a ajuda, irei reestruturar meu projeto agora mesmo, tenho 14 pastas nele e não seguem um bom padrão...